# How do you manage change of language/terminology in a scalable way for documentation (internal communication)

Tags: terminology, design-process, documentation, document-design

As UX Designers, we change and create words for things in the UI. Sometimes those are labels, sometimes error messages etc.

I've found it very difficult to keep documentation - say confluence up to date with the correct terms. I would love to be able to insert a token in the documentation that would change a specific term en masse - but I have no idea how this could be done.

This also extends to the UI itself - how have you changed words en masse in an efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

Following...I think vocabulary/terminology management software can handle this, but it depends on your technical requirements.

There is a Sketch plug-in called Copy Editor that used to work for this. If you have a CMS, you could use GatherContent. I'd be curious to know re: Confluence as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd need to use the Confluence API for this. You could retrieve the content and post updates to replace the wording as needed.

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/How-to-edit-the-page-content-using-rest-api/qaq-p/904345